# Java : double to float type conversion is giving 'infinity' for larger values

Tags: java

Suppose if i have a variable with some random larger values of type double:

```
double d = 4786777867867868654674678346734763478673478654478967.77;
```

now if i try to convert this into float at some point in my program, the output shows 'infinity' (in eclipse IDE):

```
float f = (float)d;    // inifinty
byte b = (byte)d;      // some valid value
short s = (short)d;    // some valid value
int i = (int)d;        // some valid value
```

Can someone give me any valid answers, how it is not converting for only for float datatype ?

Comment: It’s converting for float, and failing. For the other types it is truncating to fit the smaller type.

Comment: is truncating means data loss, because that is understood for other data types, but why it is giving 'infinity' for float and failing..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a look at the result of casting this large `double` to each of the other numeric primitive types:

```
    double d = 4786777867867868654674678346734763478673478654478967.77;
    System.out.printf("float  %f\n", (float)d);
    System.out.printf("long   %d\n", (long)d);
    System.out.printf("int    %d\n", (int)d);
    System.out.printf("short  %d\n", (short)d);
    System.out.printf("byte   %d\n", (byte)d);
```

Output:

```
float Infinity
long  9223372036854775807
int   2147483647
short -1
byte  -1
```

**Float**

From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> A narrowing primitive conversion from double to float is governed by
>   the IEEE 754 rounding rules (§4.2.4). This conversion can lose
>   precision, but also lose range, resulting in a float zero from a
>   nonzero double and a **float infinity from a finite double**.

Basically, IEEE 754 mandates this behaviour. IEEE 754 sets aside a specific bit pattern to represent infinity, and all floating-point operations involving this value are defined.

**Long & Int**

The JLS states that in the case of a narrowing primitive conversion from `double` to `long` or `int`, where the value is too large to fit in the range (64 or 32 bit signed integer), the largest representable value should be used,   `Long.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`;

**Short & Byte**

In casting a `double` to a `short` or `byte`, the number is first cast to an `int`, using the rule above. It is then cast from `int` to `short` or `byte` by discarding all but the `n` lowest bits (16 for `short`, 8 for `byte`). Since all but the high bit of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` are set to 1, the `short` and `byte` values have all bits set, which corresponds to -1 in signed two's complement.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can you also explain for what values float has to show infinity .. and what does it means that "float zero from not non zero double", does it means that it can also show zero value and completely loose data..?

Comment: @IshwarMahawar values greater than Float.MAX_VALUE go to infinity. Values smaller than Float.MIN_VALUE can go to 0.

Comment: and i guess you did a tiny mistake in short & byte paragraph, it should be (16 for short and 8 for byte) ..

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle thats the answer i was looking for .. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Float range is from 1.40129846432481707e-45 to 3.40282346638528860e+38.

The double value cannot fit in it. Java specs also say:

> This conversion can lose precision, but also lose range, resulting in a float zero from a nonzero double and a float infinity from a finite double.

Comment: can you explain what loosing range means..?

Comment: @IshwarMahawar float is a smaller format and has less range.

Answer (score 0):

Double is 64 bits, float is 32 bits. Not all doubles will fit in a float.

Comment: yes, data loss is possible but why it is giving infinity only for float type conversion..?

Comment: @IshwarMahawar only `double` and `float` support a representation for infinity.